# How to store words to a file by using : x for x in List A if x not in List B?

Tags: python

I stored keywords to a list : keywords=[a,b,c,d,e]  where a,b,c,d,e can be any words 
Then i tried to create a file to store the words.

```
with open("KeyWordFile.txt", "a+",) as KeyWordFile:
    KeyWordFileItem = KeyWordFile.readlines()
    KeyWordFileItem = [word.strip() for word in KeyWordFileItem]
    KeyWordToBeStored = [x for x in keywords if x not in KeyWordFileItem]

    for x in KeyWordToBeStored: 
        KeyWordFile.write("%s\n" % x.encode("UTF-8"))
```

For the first time running the code, it success to store the words to the file.
However, when i run it again, it fails to do what i want. I only want to store the words that is not already in the file.
RESULT:

```
a

b

c

d

e

a

b

c

d

e
```

What I WANT:

```
a

b

c

d
```

I dont want any duplicate of the words appears in the file.

Comment: `open("KeyWordFile.txt", "w")` is what you are expecting?

Comment: you open it as `a+` means append.

Comment: your code works just fine when I run it. if it still not wroking for you, I would try to remove the `.encode("UTF-8")`. maybe its an encoding issue

Comment: same here, i have no problem getting the desired result.

Comment: Given the comments, it sounds like you just ran your code twice, and with the append, it added on the results twice to the same file. Try the suggestion @thefourtheye gave. (And I recommend posting it as an answer, thefourtheye. ;) )

Comment: hey guys i am going to append the file for later use. i tried @ndpu method and it works. i think it is simply a decoding problem and it is ok now. thanks for everyone giving your thought on it :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `decode` here if you are using unicode chars in test:

```
#KeyWordFileItem = [word.strip() for word in KeyWordFileItem]
KeyWordFileItem = [word.decode('utf-8').strip() for word in KeyWordFileItem]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 steps and using a set()

```
with open("KeyWordFile.txt", "rt") as myfile:
    keywords = set([kw.strip() for kw in myfile])

with open("KeyWordFile.txt", "wt") as myfile:
    for kw in sorted(keywords):
        myfile.write("%s\n" % kw.encode("UTF-8"))
```

I think you need the keywords sorted, otherwise you can remove the `sorted()` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you open file with flag `a+`, your file cursor will automatically locate at the end of the file, so your can read nothing out of the file. One method to fix this is to use `seek(0)`
 method to rewind the cursor

```
with open("KeyWordFile.txt", "a+",) as KeyWordFile:
    KeyWordFile.seek(0)
    KeyWordFileItem = KeyWordFile.readlines()
    KeyWordFileItem = [word.strip() for word in KeyWordFileItem]
    KeyWordToBeStored = [x for x in keywords if x not in KeyWordFileItem]

    for x in KeyWordToBeStored: 
        KeyWordFile.write("%s\n" % x.encode("UTF-8"))
```

But be careful when you call `write` before `read` , cause `write` will move the cursor to `EOF` , maybe your can try to seperate those two parts